# Kubernetes Helm Elasticstack CrashLoopBackOff with JavaErrors in Log

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I'm trying to deploy the ELK stack to my developing kubernetes cluster. It seems that I do everything as described in the tutorials, however, the pods keep failing with Java errors (see below). I will describe the whole process from installing the cluster until the error happens.

Step 1: Installing the cluster

```
# Apply sysctl params without reboot

cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/modules-load.d/containerd.conf
overlay
br_netfilter
EOF

sudo modprobe overlay
sudo modprobe br_netfilter

# Setup required sysctl params, these persist across reboots.
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/sysctl.d/99-kubernetes-cri.conf
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables  = 1
net.ipv4.ip_forward                 = 1
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 1
EOF

sudo sysctl --system
#update and install apt https stuff
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg lsb-release
# add docker repo for containerd and install it
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg
 echo \
  "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
  $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y containerd.io

# copy config
sudo mkdir -p /etc/containerd
containerd config default | sudo tee /etc/containerd/config.toml
sudo systemctl restart containerd
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/modules-load.d/k8s.conf
br_netfilter
EOF

cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/sysctl.d/k8s.conf
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 1 // somewhat redundant
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 1 // somewhat redundant
EOF
sudo sysctl --system

#install kubernetes binaries
sudo curl -fsSLo /usr/share/keyrings/kubernetes-archive-keyring.gpg https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/kubernetes-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl
sudo apt-mark hold kubelet kubeadm kubectl

#disable swap and comment swap in fstab
sudo swapoff -v /dev/mapper/main-swap
sudo nano /etc/fstab

#init cluster
sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16
#make user to kubectl admin
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config

#install calico
kubectl apply -f 
kubectl create -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/manifests/tigera-operator.yaml
kubectl create -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/manifests/custom-resources.yaml
    
#untaint master node that pods can run on it
kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-

#install helm
curl https://baltocdn.com/helm/signing.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https --yes
echo "deb https://baltocdn.com/helm/stable/debian/ all main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/helm-stable-debian.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install helm
```

Step 2: Install ECK (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-install-helm.html) and elasticsearch (https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/blob/master/elasticsearch/README.md#installing)

```
# add helm repo
helm repo add elastic https://helm.elastic.co
helm repo update
# install eck
####  ommited as suggested in comment section!!!! helm install elastic-operator elastic/eck-operator -n elastic-system --create-namespace
helm install elasticsearch elastic/elasticsearch
```

Step 3: Add PersistentVolume

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: elk-data1
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 30Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data1"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: elk-data2
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 30Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data2"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: elk-data3
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 30Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data3"
```

apply it

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/data1
sudo mkdir /mnt/data2
sudo mkdir /mnt/data3
kubectl apply -f storage.yaml
```

Now the pods (or at least one) sould run. But I keep getting STATUS CrashLoopBackOff with java errors in the log.

```
kubectl get pv,pvc,pods

NAME                         CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                                                 STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
persistentvolume/elk-data1   30Gi       RWO            Retain           Bound    default/elasticsearch-master-elasticsearch-master-1                           140m
persistentvolume/elk-data2   30Gi       RWO            Retain           Bound    default/elasticsearch-master-elasticsearch-master-2                           140m
persistentvolume/elk-data3   30Gi       RWO            Retain           Bound    default/elasticsearch-master-elasticsearch-master-0                           140m

NAME                                                                STATUS   VOLUME      CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
persistentvolumeclaim/elasticsearch-master-elasticsearch-master-0   Bound    elk-data3   30Gi       RWO                           141m
persistentvolumeclaim/elasticsearch-master-elasticsearch-master-1   Bound    elk-data1   30Gi       RWO                           141m
persistentvolumeclaim/elasticsearch-master-elasticsearch-master-2   Bound    elk-data2   30Gi       RWO                           141m

NAME                         READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
pod/elasticsearch-master-0   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   32         141m
pod/elasticsearch-master-1   0/1     Pending            0          141m
pod/elasticsearch-master-2   0/1     Pending            0          141m
```

Logs and Error:

```
kubectl logs pod/elasticsearch-master-2


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.Metrics.systemMetrics(Metrics.java:65)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.Container.metrics(Container.java:43)
        at jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal.OperatingSystemImpl.<init>(OperatingSystemImpl.java:48)
        at jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal.PlatformMBeanProviderImpl.getOperatingSystemMXBean(PlatformMBeanProviderImpl.java:279)
        at jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal.PlatformMBeanProviderImpl$3.nameToMBeanMap(PlatformMBeanProviderImpl.java:198)
        at java.management/java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.lambda$getPlatformMBeanServer$0(ManagementFactory.java:487)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:273)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
        at java.base/java.util.HashMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1766)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596)
        at java.management/java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer(ManagementFactory.java:488)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server.reregisterMBeansAfterReconfigure(Server.java:140)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:558)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:263)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:207)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator.initialize(Configurator.java:220)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator.initialize(Configurator.java:197)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configureStatusLogger(LogConfigurator.java:248)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configureWithoutConfig(LogConfigurator.java:95)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.CommandLoggingConfigurator.configureLoggingWithoutConfig(CommandLoggingConfigurator.java:29)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:76)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.KeyStoreCli.main(KeyStoreCli.java:32)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.Metrics.systemMetrics(Metrics.java:61)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.CgroupSubsystemFactory.create(CgroupSubsystemFactory.java:107)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.CgroupMetrics.getInstance(CgroupMetrics.java:167)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:208)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystem.getPath(UnixFileSystem.java:260)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Path.of(Path.java:147)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:69)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.CgroupUtil.lambda$readStringValue$1(CgroupUtil.java:66)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:554)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.CgroupUtil.readStringValue(CgroupUtil.java:68)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.CgroupSubsystemController.getStringValue(CgroupSubsystemController.java:65)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.CgroupSubsystemController.getLongValue(CgroupSubsystemController.java:124)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.cgroupv1.CgroupV1Subsystem.getLongValue(CgroupV1Subsystem.java:272)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.cgroupv1.CgroupV1Subsystem.getHierarchical(CgroupV1Subsystem.java:218)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.cgroupv1.CgroupV1Subsystem.setPath(CgroupV1Subsystem.java:201)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.cgroupv1.CgroupV1Subsystem.setSubSystemControllerPath(CgroupV1Subsystem.java:173)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.cgroupv1.CgroupV1Subsystem.lambda$initSubSystem$5(CgroupV1Subsystem.java:113)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
        at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
        at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.cgroupv1.CgroupV1Subsystem.initSubSystem(CgroupV1Subsystem.java:113)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.cgroupv1.CgroupV1Subsystem.<clinit>(CgroupV1Subsystem.java:47)
        ... 33 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.Metrics.systemMetrics(Metrics.java:65)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.Container.metrics(Container.java:43)
        at jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal.OperatingSystemImpl.<init>(OperatingSystemImpl.java:48)
        at jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal.PlatformMBeanProviderImpl.getOperatingSystemMXBean(PlatformMBeanProviderImpl.java:279)
        at jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal.PlatformMBeanProviderImpl$3.nameToMBeanMap(PlatformMBeanProviderImpl.java:198)
        at java.management/sun.management.spi.PlatformMBeanProvider$PlatformComponent.getMBeans(PlatformMBeanProvider.java:195)
        at java.management/java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMXBean(ManagementFactory.java:686)
        at java.management/java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean(ManagementFactory.java:388)
        at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.DefaultSystemMemoryInfo.<init>(DefaultSystemMemoryInfo.java:28)
        at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOptionsParser.jvmOptions(JvmOptionsParser.java:125)
        at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOptionsParser.main(JvmOptionsParser.java:86)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.Metrics.systemMetrics(Metrics.java:61)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.CgroupSubsystemFactory.create(CgroupSubsystemFactory.java:107)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.CgroupMetrics.getInstance(CgroupMetrics.java:167)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:208)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystem.getPath(UnixFileSystem.java:260)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Path.of(Path.java:147)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:69)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.CgroupUtil.lambda$readStringValue$1(CgroupUtil.java:66)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:554)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.CgroupUtil.readStringValue(CgroupUtil.java:68)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.CgroupSubsystemController.getStringValue(CgroupSubsystemController.java:65)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.CgroupSubsystemController.getLongValue(CgroupSubsystemController.java:124)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.cgroupv1.CgroupV1Subsystem.getLongValue(CgroupV1Subsystem.java:272)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.cgroupv1.CgroupV1Subsystem.getHierarchical(CgroupV1Subsystem.java:218)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.cgroupv1.CgroupV1Subsystem.setPath(CgroupV1Subsystem.java:201)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.cgroupv1.CgroupV1Subsystem.setSubSystemControllerPath(CgroupV1Subsystem.java:173)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.cgroupv1.CgroupV1Subsystem.lambda$initSubSystem$5(CgroupV1Subsystem.java:113)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
        at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
        at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.cgroupv1.CgroupV1Subsystem.initSubSystem(CgroupV1Subsystem.java:113)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.platform.cgroupv1.CgroupV1Subsystem.<clinit>(CgroupV1Subsystem.java:47)
        ... 17 more
```

values.yaml from helm chart

```
---
clusterName: "elasticsearch"
nodeGroup: "master"

# The service that non master groups will try to connect to when joining the cluster
# This should be set to clusterName + "-" + nodeGroup for your master group
masterService: ""

# Elasticsearch roles that will be applied to this nodeGroup
# These will be set as environment variables. E.g. node.master=true
roles:
  master: "true"
  ingest: "true"
  data: "true"
  remote_cluster_client: "true"
  ml: "true"

replicas: 3
minimumMasterNodes: 2

esMajorVersion: ""

# Allows you to add any config files in /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/
# such as elasticsearch.yml and log4j2.properties
esConfig: {}
#  elasticsearch.yml: |
#    key:
#      nestedkey: value
#  log4j2.properties: |
#    key = value

# Extra environment variables to append to this nodeGroup
# This will be appended to the current 'env:' key. You can use any of the kubernetes env
# syntax here
extraEnvs: []
#  - name: MY_ENVIRONMENT_VAR
#    value: the_value_goes_here

# Allows you to load environment variables from kubernetes secret or config map
envFrom: []
# - secretRef:
#     name: env-secret
# - configMapRef:
#     name: config-map

# A list of secrets and their paths to mount inside the pod
# This is useful for mounting certificates for security and for mounting
# the X-Pack license
secretMounts: []
#  - name: elastic-certificates
#    secretName: elastic-certificates
#    path: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
#    defaultMode: 0755

hostAliases: []
#- ip: "127.0.0.1"
#  hostnames:
#  - "foo.local"
#  - "bar.local"

image: "docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch"
imageTag: "7.12.1"
imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"

podAnnotations: {}
  # iam.amazonaws.com/role: es-cluster

# additionals labels
labels: {}

esJavaOpts: "-Xmx1g -Xms1g"

resources:
  requests:
    cpu: "1000m"
    memory: "2Gi"
  limits:
    cpu: "1000m"
    memory: "2Gi"

initResources: {}
  # limits:
  #   cpu: "25m"
  #   # memory: "128Mi"
  # requests:
  #   cpu: "25m"
  #   memory: "128Mi"

sidecarResources: {}
  # limits:
  #   cpu: "25m"
  #   # memory: "128Mi"
  # requests:
  #   cpu: "25m"
  #   memory: "128Mi"

networkHost: "0.0.0.0"

volumeClaimTemplate:
  accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 30Gi

rbac:
  create: false
  serviceAccountAnnotations: {}
  serviceAccountName: ""

podSecurityPolicy:
  create: false
  name: ""
  spec:
    privileged: true
    fsGroup:
      rule: RunAsAny
    runAsUser:
      rule: RunAsAny
    seLinux:
      rule: RunAsAny
    supplementalGroups:
      rule: RunAsAny
    volumes:
      - secret
      - configMap
      - persistentVolumeClaim
      - emptyDir

persistence:
  enabled: true
  labels:
    # Add default labels for the volumeClaimTemplate of the StatefulSet
    enabled: false
  annotations: {}

extraVolumes: []
  # - name: extras
  #   emptyDir: {}

extraVolumeMounts: []
  # - name: extras
  #   mountPath: /usr/share/extras
  #   readOnly: true

extraContainers: []
  # - name: do-something
  #   image: busybox
  #   command: ['do', 'something']

extraInitContainers: []
  # - name: do-something
  #   image: busybox
  #   command: ['do', 'something']

# This is the PriorityClass settings as defined in
# https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/pod-priority-preemption/#priorityclass
priorityClassName: ""

# By default this will make sure two pods don't end up on the same node
# Changing this to a region would allow you to spread pods across regions
antiAffinityTopologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"

# Hard means that by default pods will only be scheduled if there are enough nodes for them
# and that they will never end up on the same node. Setting this to soft will do this "best effort"
antiAffinity: "hard"

# This is the node affinity settings as defined in
# https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#node-affinity-beta-feature
nodeAffinity: {}

# The default is to deploy all pods serially. By setting this to parallel all pods are started at
# the same time when bootstrapping the cluster
podManagementPolicy: "Parallel"

# The environment variables injected by service links are not used, but can lead to slow Elasticsearch boot times when
# there are many services in the current namespace.
# If you experience slow pod startups you probably want to set this to `false`.
enableServiceLinks: true

protocol: http
httpPort: 9200
transportPort: 9300

service:
  labels: {}
  labelsHeadless: {}
  type: ClusterIP
  nodePort: ""
  annotations: {}
  httpPortName: http
  transportPortName: transport
  loadBalancerIP: ""
  loadBalancerSourceRanges: []
  externalTrafficPolicy: ""

updateStrategy: RollingUpdate

# This is the max unavailable setting for the pod disruption budget
# The default value of 1 will make sure that kubernetes won't allow more than 1
# of your pods to be unavailable during maintenance
maxUnavailable: 1

podSecurityContext:
  fsGroup: 1000
  runAsUser: 1000

securityContext:
  capabilities:
    drop:
    - ALL
  # readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
  runAsNonRoot: true
  runAsUser: 1000

# How long to wait for elasticsearch to stop gracefully
terminationGracePeriod: 120

sysctlVmMaxMapCount: 262144

readinessProbe:
  failureThreshold: 3
  initialDelaySeconds: 10
  periodSeconds: 10
  successThreshold: 3
  timeoutSeconds: 5

# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.12/cluster-health.html#request-params wait_for_status
clusterHealthCheckParams: "wait_for_status=green&timeout=1s"

## Use an alternate scheduler.
## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-multiple-schedulers/
##
schedulerName: ""

imagePullSecrets: []
nodeSelector: {}
tolerations: []

# Enabling this will publically expose your Elasticsearch instance.
# Only enable this if you have security enabled on your cluster
ingress:
  enabled: false
  annotations: {}
    # kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    # kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
  hosts:
    - host: chart-example.local
      paths:
        - path: /
  tls: []
  #  - secretName: chart-example-tls
  #    hosts:
  #      - chart-example.local

nameOverride: ""
fullnameOverride: ""

# https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/issues/63
masterTerminationFix: false

lifecycle: {}
  # preStop:
  #   exec:
  #     command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo Hello from the postStart handler > /usr/share/message"]
  # postStart:
  #   exec:
  #     command:
  #       - bash
  #       - -c
  #       - |
  #         #!/bin/bash
  #         # Add a template to adjust number of shards/replicas
  #         TEMPLATE_NAME=my_template
  #         INDEX_PATTERN="logstash-*"
  #         SHARD_COUNT=8
  #         REPLICA_COUNT=1
  #         ES_URL=http://localhost:9200
  #         while [[ "$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}\n' $ES_URL)" != "200" ]]; do sleep 1; done
  #         curl -XPUT "$ES_URL/_template/$TEMPLATE_NAME" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"index_patterns":['\""$INDEX_PATTERN"\"'],"settings":{"number_of_shards":'$SHARD_COUNT',"number_of_replicas":'$REPLICA_COUNT'}}'

sysctlInitContainer:
  enabled: true

keystore: []

networkPolicy:
  ## Enable creation of NetworkPolicy resources. Only Ingress traffic is filtered for now.
  ## In order for a Pod to access Elasticsearch, it needs to have the following label:
  ## {{ template "uname" . }}-client: "true"
  ## Example for default configuration to access HTTP port:
  ## elasticsearch-master-http-client: "true"
  ## Example for default configuration to access transport port:
  ## elasticsearch-master-transport-client: "true"

  http:
    enabled: false
    ## if explicitNamespacesSelector is not set or set to {}, only client Pods being in the networkPolicy's namespace
    ## and matching all criteria can reach the DB.
    ## But sometimes, we want the Pods to be accessible to clients from other namespaces, in this case, we can use this
    ## parameter to select these namespaces
    ##
    # explicitNamespacesSelector:
    #   # Accept from namespaces with all those different rules (only from whitelisted Pods)
    #   matchLabels:
    #     role: frontend
    #   matchExpressions:
    #     - {key: role, operator: In, values: [frontend]}

    ## Additional NetworkPolicy Ingress "from" rules to set. Note that all rules are OR-ed.
    ##
    # additionalRules:
    #   - podSelector:
    #       matchLabels:
    #         role: frontend
    #   - podSelector:
    #       matchExpressions:
    #         - key: role
    #           operator: In
    #           values:
    #             - frontend

  transport:
    ## Note that all Elasticsearch Pods can talks to themselves using transport port even if enabled.
    enabled: false
    # explicitNamespacesSelector:
    #   matchLabels:
    #     role: frontend
    #   matchExpressions:
    #     - {key: role, operator: In, values: [frontend]}
    # additionalRules:
    #   - podSelector:
    #       matchLabels:
    #         role: frontend
    #   - podSelector:
    #       matchExpressions:
    #         - key: role
    #           operator: In
    #           values:
    #             - frontend

# Deprecated
# please use the above podSecurityContext.fsGroup instead
fsGroup: ""
```

Comment: Do you have more log output?
Seems like the actual info is hidden under such rows like "... 17 more".

Comment: Did you fix folder permissions of "/mnt/data2" after pod creation?
I had similar problem when deployed Prometheus with manual PV provisioning - app runned under 1001 uid, but local PV folder was created by Kubernetes under root owner.
So it caused write unavailability.

Comment: @DenisRomaniuk I tried with "chown -R 1000:1000 /mnt/data*" to fix permissions (values.yaml says runAsUser: 1000 as you can see above). The error persists. I tried to print the full log with "kubectl logs --tail=-1" but it still is printed like shown above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are experiencing is not an issue related to Elasticsearch. It is a problem resulting from the cgroup configuration for the version of containerd you are using. I haven't unpacked the specifics, but the exception in the Elasticsearch logs relates to the JDK failing when attempting to retrieve the required cgroup information.

I had the same issue and resolved it by executing the following steps, before installing Kubernetes,  to install a later version of containerd and configure it to use cgroups with systemd:

1. Add the GPG key for the official Docker repository.

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

2. Add the Docker repository to APT sources.

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable"
```

3. Install the latest containerd.io package instead of the containerd package from Ubuntu.

```
apt-get -y install containerd.io
```

4. Generate the default containerd configuration.

```
containerd config default > /etc/containerd/config.toml
```

5. Configure containerd to use systemd to manage the cgroups.

```
    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.runtimes.runc]
     runtime_type = "io.containerd.runc.v2"
     runtime_engine = ""
     runtime_root = ""
     privileged_without_host_devices = false
     base_runtime_spec = ""
     [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.runtimes.runc.options]
      SystemdCgroup = true
```

6. Restart the containerd service.

```
systemctl restart containerd
```

Comment: I do not know what to say. This line was missing "SystemdCgroup = true" in /etc/containerd/config.toml
You have my deepest gratitude. Firstly, for making an account just to answer, secondly for providing the right answer.
You maybe want to update your answer to highlight the specific line that was missing

Answer (score 0):

For the ELK stack to work you need all three PersistentVolumeClaim's to be bound as I recall. Instead of creating 1 30 GB of PV create 3 of the same size with the claims and then re-install. Other nodes have unmet dependincies.

Also please do not handle the volumes by hand. There are guidelines to deploy dynamic volums. Use OpenEBS for example. That way you wont need to worry about the pvc's. After giving the pv's if anything happens write again with your cluster installation process.

---

I was wrong obviously, in this particular problem, filesystems and cgroups take role and the main problem of this is an old problem. From 5.2.1 to 8.0.0.
Reinstall the chart by pulling the chart. Edit values file and definitely change the container version. It should be fine or create another error log stack.

Comment: I apologize - I already tried that. I updated my post to reflect what I did to bind all three pods to volumes.

Comment: Addition: Even if I scale down the replicas to 1, the error still happens.

Comment: Why did you install the operator as well? Can you remove the charts and only install elasticsearch with a different release name `helm install elastic -f values.yaml .` from the chart directory must be fine? Also please update the chart repository.

Comment: I do not have a chart directory, the commands I used to install elasticsearch + the operator were from the according to the tutorial sections (elastic website and helm repository). I installed the operator because the tutorial said it is necessary, isn't it?
How do I update the chart repository? -> I did 'helm repo update'
Where can I get a different release/chart?
Can I remove the operator?

Comment: But the websites tell you to install only one?

Comment: I cannot see any mention of that on the linked site. Isnt the operator necessary to run elasticsearch with helm? What is wrong with my setup?

Comment: For both pages, installing it consists of either operator or elastic packet but this should not be the issue. Can you pull the charts and check the values in the values.yaml file and compare to your system? Maybe insufficient resources or disk write speed is low. By the way, what is the filesystem and distro on the server ? Filesystem errors can happen because of the server too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232892/discussion-between-catastrophe-and-i-shm).

Comment: Hey, Do you got any suggestion I am in ditto situation.

Answer (score 0):

Get it solved down to the 7.11.x version.
My kubernetes version is v1.13.x